# How to parse json that contains "." in its key name

Tags: jsonparser

```
{
    "key" : "value",
    "array.fruits" : [
        { "key" : 1 },
        { "key" : 2, "dictionary": {
                "a": "Apple",
                "b": "Butterfly",
                "c": "Cat",
                "d": "Dog"
            } },
        { "key" : 3 }
    ]
}
```

How to parse the key 'array.fruits' in json query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [bracket notation property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) in order to get to the value you need:

```js
const data = {
    "key" : "value",
    "array.fruits" : [
        { "key" : 1 },
        { "key" : 2, "dictionary": {
                "a": "Apple",
                "b": "Butterfly",
                "c": "Cat",
                "d": "Dog"
            } },
        { "key" : 3 }
    ]
}

console.dir(data["array.fruits"])
```